# Iterating through Models Attributes in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have a model that requests a JSON file like below:

```
[
{
    "ModifiedOn": "2015-04-08 11:17:28.0",
    "BuildingCode": "AU1010A1",
    "BuildingName": "REGUS - BRISBANE",
    "ActionRequired": "A"
},
{
    "ModifiedOn": "2015-04-08 11:17:28.0",
    "BuildingCode": "BR1044A1",
    "BuildingName": "RIO SUL - RIO DE JANEIRO",
    "ActionRequired": "A"
}]
```

In the console I can see the attributes like so

[image]

However when I try and access the model attributes like so, I am getting undefined.

```
console.log(this.model.attributes.length);
```

I tried parsing to JSON but that failed.

Do I have to access each individual object in the attributes array my model has?

Comment: I changed my approach to this and used a collection of building models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this one.

```
//for array[object{}, object{},...]
for(var i = 0; i <data.length;i++)
{
    foreach(var key in data[i])
    {
        //print out the attributes for data[i].
        console.log(key);
        //print out the attribute values.
        console.log(data[i][key]);
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

```
//for object{object{}, object{},...}
foreach(var childObject in data)
{
    foreach(var key in childObject)
    {
        //print out the attributes for childObject.
        console.log(key);
        //print out the attribute values.
        console.log(childObject[key]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I tried this, but data.length is giving a value of zero. So the loop never executes. So I need to get the total amount of attributes before I can loop through them

Comment: Do you replacce the variable data?
You need to pass or replace the variable **data** for the response of server or anything that contains the array of objects.

Comment: Yes I did, the problem is the structure is like this when I look in the console.

`object { object {}, object{}, object{}}`

Answer (score 1):

Its an object so you can use `Object.keys(this.model.attributes)`.

Comment: Ok, I tried that code and got a length of zero

`console.log(Object.keys(this.model.attributes).length);`

Comment: @loosebruce without more context, i can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toJSON()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON), `for in` loop to iterate through model attributes

```
var attrs = this.model.toJSON();
for(key in attrs){
   console.log((key + " -> " + attrs[key]);)
}
```